# How do you copy a state machine class in python?

Tags: python, copy, state-machine

The below self contained code snippet defines a simple state machine and uses the copy module to make copies of it.

```
import copy
class StateMachine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.doit = self._doit_A
    def _doit_A(self):
        print('state A')
        self.doit = self._doit_B
    def _doit_B(self):
        print('state B')
        self.doit = self._doit_A

sm = StateMachine()
sm_copy_before_changes = copy.copy(sm)

print('--- Original StateMachine ---')
for _ in range(3): sm.doit()

print('--- pre copy ---')
for _ in range(3): sm_copy_before_changes.doit()

sm_copy_after_changes = copy.copy(sm)
print('--- post copy ---')
for _ in range(3): sm_copy_after_changes.doit()
```

The output is

```
--- Original StateMachine ---
state A
state B
state A
--- pre copy ---
state A
state A
state A
--- post copy ---
state B
state B
state B
```

The original state machine works as expected switching from one state to the next on subsequent `doit()` calls.

The copy made before any `doit()` calls were made on the original is stuck in state A

The copy made after `doit()` calls were made in the original is stuck in state B

**Why is this not working and what's the best way to make the copies work as expected?**

`deepcopy()` makes it work. What is `copy()` ignoring that `deepcopy()` doesn't ignore in this case?

In the real world situation in front of me, I don't want to `deepcopy()` the state machine. presumably I can redefine `__copy__()`? How would I do that in this case? or should I redefine `__deepcopy__()`?

Comment: i'm not sure if I understand it correctly, please see my answer and tell me if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just need to inspect the objects:

```py
assert sm.doit == sm_copy_before_changes.doit
sm_copy_before_changes, sm, sm_copy_before_changes.doit
```

gives:

```py
<__main__.StateMachine at 0x7f0b649d6cc0>,
<__main__.StateMachine at 0x7f0b649d6d30>,
<bound method StateMachine._doit_A of <__main__.StateMachine object at 0x7f0b649d6d30>>
```

So, **when you `copy`, you create a new object - but, its `doit` still refers to the `doit` object of `sm`** - so, obviously it's stuck at one state.

Now, let's try deepcopy!

```py
sm_before_2 = copy.deepcopy(sm)

assert sm_before_2.doit != sm.doit
sm_before_2, sm_before_2.doit
```

gives:

```py
<__main__.StateMachine at 0x7f0b64a66a90>,
<bound method StateMachine._doit_A of <__main__.StateMachine object at 0x7f0b64a66a90>>
```

Well, that would obviously work now!

And this is somewhat alluded to in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

> A shallow copy constructs a new compound object and then (to the extent possible) inserts references into it to the objects found in the original.
>
> A deep copy constructs a new compound object and then, recursively, inserts copies into it of the objects found in the original.

---

---

#### hacking `__copy__`:

one very quick way of hacking `__copy__` to enable the behaviour you want would be:

```py
    def __copy__(self):
      new = self.__class__()
      for i in dir(self):
        if i != '__weakref__':
          setattr(new, i, getattr(self, i))
      return new
```

obviously, be **careful** to test this out - so that there aren't any unintended consequences in your app!

Comment: Thanks Partha. So it seems python methods are linked to the object instances on which they operate and the calling object may or may not be the same, as opposed to the C++ model where methods are linked to the class and the calling instance determines the object they operate on. Fair enough. So how would I override `__copy__()` in this instance to get the C++ style behavior? I don't want to rely on `deepcopy()` as it does not suit the real life use case.

Comment: @OldSchool I would be curious to know why you are a bit apprehensive about `deepcopy` - I mean obvious;y as you said you have a real world issue - but, what exactly (if it can be briefed upon)?

Comment: @OldSchool also, added a quick hack to overload `__copy__`

Comment: The real world state machines hold references to large structures which do not need to be copied. That's the reason I don't want to deepcopy

Comment: When you say "hack": what in your implementation concerns you as a hack? What is the canonical best way to override __copy__() for this class to get the behavior I've described?

Comment: @OldSchool I would think then what you would want is `deepcopy` but omitting those specific large structures! So, I would look into overriding `__deepcopy__`. And I called it "hack" beacuse `__copy__` is not really suitable for the job - I just copied everything in a new object - but, the underlying stuff is still from old one!